# Не могу объединить две матрицы, чтобы получить матрицу с комплексными числами

Tags: python, матрицы

Используя такую программу

```
    # Чтение данных из файла txt
with open('Y1.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
# Преобразование строк в числа с плавающей точкой и разделение на строки
matrix = [list(map(lambda x: float(x.replace(',', '.')), Y1.split())) for Y1 in data]
# Вывод матрицы
for Y1 in matrix:
    print(Y1)
# Чтение данных из файла txt
with open('Y2.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
# Преобразование строк в числа с плавающей точкой и разделение на строки
matrix = [list(map(lambda x: float(x.replace(',', '.')), Y2.split())) for Y2 in data]
# Вывод матрицы
for Y2 in matrix:
    print(Y2)
# Создание матрицы с комплексными числами
complex_matrix = []
for i in range(len(Y1)):
    Y = []
    for j in range(len(Y1[i])):
        complex_num = complex(Y1[i][j], Y2[i][j])
        Y.append(complex_num)
    complex_matrix.append(Y)
# Вывод результата
for Y in complex_matrix:
    print(Y)
```

выдает ошибку TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len(). Т.е. матрицы из файлов инициализируются, а объединить не получается

Comment: `Y1` - последняя строка первой матрицы. `Y2` - последняя строка второй матрицы. `matrix` - вторая матрица. Первую матрицу вы потеряли.

Comment: Спасибо большое, не заметила